# slicing a string in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript

All I am doing in this function is:

```
function parse_msg(chatstr) {

    let i = chatstr.indexOf(',');
    var msg = chatstr.slice(i+1);
    return msg;
}
```

parse a message that first starts with username then ',' then the actual message. 
but when I print the result I get the full message again! so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the input you are providing?

Comment: It seems correct to me, try `console.log(parse_msg('bob,hello world'))` and you will get what you expect

Comment: I got hello world. it seems correct as a function. I'll more info on the input.

Answer (score 0):

So the function is good as is, but something is wrong with my code here:

in this I call input:

```
  document.querySelector('#select_channels').onchange = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('channel',this.value);
    let x = document.getElementById('chat_msg_head');
    x.innerHTML = '#' + this.value;

    // get all the chats for this channel
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/chats');

    // Callback function for when request completes
    request.onload = () => {
    // Extract JSON data from request
        const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

        // Update the result div
        if (data.success) {
          chats = data.chats;
          if (chats) {
            alert(`chats is ${chats}`);
            let length = chats.length;
            for (i =0 ;i <length; i++)
            {

              let user = parse_user(chats[i]);
              let msg = parse_msg(chats[i]);
              alert(` user is ${user} and message is ${msg}`);
              //fill_in_recent(user,msg);
            }
```

also the alert `${msg}` prints the full message including user and ',' and not the actual message as it supposed to print.

my specific alert was:  'user is rajasaid and message is rajasaid,Hi this is the first message built-in'

Answer (score 0):

you can use split insted of slice

```
function parse_msg(chatstr) {
        var msg = chatstr.split(',');
        return msg;
    }
    console.log(parse_msg('name,message'));
```

Comment: I get the following error - Uncaught TypeError: chatstr.split is not a function. what do I do to include split ?

Comment: thanks, the split function worked. it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the built-in String  function [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)? It splits your string into an array of strings, based on a given character.

```
let input = 'my_username,my_message';

function parseString (str) {
   let result = str.split(','); // 

   let username = result[0]; // Which is equal to "my_username"
   let message = result[1]; // Which is equal to "my_message"

   return message;
}

parseString(input);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: chatstr.split is not a function

Comment: what should I do to include the split function, maybe my javascript version is not good enough?

Comment: It's supported since ECMAScript 1. Happy to be helpful.